# Switch Python installation from 32 to 64 bit

Tags: windows-10, powershell, python

historically, I've used 32 bit python, but I'm currently trying to install the 64 bit version.

I've downloaded the amd64 executable and run it.

It installed successfully.

The installation location though is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64`.

This is not currently in `Path`.

Should I change the installation location to `C:Program Files` where it's expected to be and add that to `Path`

If I add it to `Path` how then would I specify whether to use the 32 or 64 bit versions?

I understand that the version that is listed first will be the default, I need access to each from powershell.

Comment: Which installer did you use? It's been a while since I've used Python on Windows, but shouldn't it be installed somewhere else, and offer (during the installation wizard) to add itself to the PATH? (See https://www.howtogeek.com/197947/how-to-install-python-on-windows/)

Comment: yeah, I'm using the installer listed in that page, initially didn't choose the option to add the 64 bit version to Path because I didn't want to lose the 32 bit installation. Redid it adding to path. So I can use 64 bit installation by default now.

Comment: so I guess the essential question is: how do I use the non-default installation whichever one it is?

Comment: @Hugh_Kelley I think this answer details how to do what you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/66102653 (have multiple versions of python installed, and choose which one to use by changing the order of the python paths in the path environment variable i.e. the first python path is the one that runs by default)

Comment: Thanks @jlo that answer makes sense to me. Since asking this question I believe that I figured out a solution to my problem that solved the memory limitations I was running into a different way. If you want to post that answer on this Q I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When having multiple versions of python installed, the version used by default is the first python path that appears in the path environment variable.

One simple way to check in Windows/cmd is

```
for %A IN ("%PATH:;=" "%") DO @ECHO=%~A | Find /I "Python"
```

which in my case outputs

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\
```

which means, 64-bit version runs as default. Also remember to restart the cmd window for it to detect the new path after you've edited it.